# Format manipulators (c++)

Tags: c++, format, double

The setprecision(2) and field width manipulators aren't working. When i execute the double subtraction it is rounding the numbers to decimals. and the inputs are not right justified or field width of 6. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Runs a program with a menu that the user can navigate through different options with via text input

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char userinp;
    while (true)
    {   
        cout<<"Here is the menu:" << endl;
        cout<<"Help(H)      addIntegers(A)      subDoubles(D)           Quit(Q)" << endl;

        cin >> userinp;
        userinp = tolower(userinp);

        if (userinp == 'h')
        {   
            cout <<"This is the help menu. Upon returning to the main menu, input A or a to add 2 intergers." << endl;
            cout <<"Input D or d to subtract 2 doubles. Input Q or q to quit." << endl;
        }

        else if (userinp == 'a')
        {
            int add1, add2, sum;
            cout <<"Enter two integers:";
            cin >> add1 >> add2;
            sum = add1 + add2;
            cout << setw(6) << setiosflags(ios::right) << "The sum of " << add1 << " + " << add2 << " = " << sum << endl;
        }
        else if (userinp == 'd')
        {
            double sub1, sub2, difference;
            cout.fixed;
            cout <<"Enter two doubles:";
            cin >> sub1 >> sub2;
            difference = sub1 - sub2;
            cout << setw(6) << setiosflags(ios::right) << setprecision(2) << "The difference of " << sub1 << " - " << sub2 << " = " << difference << endl;
        }
        else if (userinp == 'q')
        {
            cout <<"Program will exit, goodbye!";
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
        cout <<"Please input a valid character to navigate the menu - input the letter h for the help menu";
        cout << "Press any key to continue" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual input / output (console session) that demonstrates the problem? Are you sure the code you show is the code you compiled?

Comment: I've recompiled and rebuilt over and over and still nothing. Here is the output:

Here is the menu:
Help(H)         addIntegers(A)          subDoubles(D)                   Quit(Q)
d
Enter two doubles:43.3 33.5
The difference of 43 - 34 = 9.8

Answer (score 0):

The `width()` is the only manipulator which isn't sticky: it applies to the next formatted output, in your case to the printing of the string literal. You should put the use of `std::setw()` right in front of the value you want to format, e.g.:

```
cout << std::right << std::setprecision(2) << "The difference of "
     << std::setw(6) << sub1 << " - "
     << std::setw(6) << sub2 << " = "
     << std::setw(6) << difference << '\n';
```

I'm not sure what you are referring to with respect to the precision. You might want to also use `std::fixed`.

Comment: `setprecision` results in just two digits - so `123.45678` becomes `1.2e+02`. I don't think that is what OP is after. He wants `123.45`.

Comment: set(w) is now working with this change. setprecision(2) is supposed to display doubles with two digits after the decimal, correct? It's not doing that for some reason..

Comment: Use `std::cout << std::fixed;` before formatting the `double` values.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on Dietmar's answer, in order to get two digits after the decimal you need

```
cout << std::right << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "The difference of "
     << std::setw(6) << sub1 << " - "
     << std::setw(6) << sub2 << " = "
     << std::setw(6) << difference << '\n';
```

Adding the `std::fixed` solves the problem you were having.

Demonstration:

```
Here is the menu:
Help(H)      addIntegers(A)      subDoubles(D)           Quit(Q)
d
Enter two doubles:123.456
23.4
The difference of 123.46 -  23.40 = 100.06
Here is the menu:
Help(H)      addIntegers(A)      subDoubles(D)           Quit(Q)
```

Comment: I guess I had std::fixed in the wrong location, it has to be on the same cout line of code that is to be executed? Thank you very much, by the way.

Comment: Yes - format specifiers tend to be very particular about where they are. For this reason I am a big fan of using `printf` for situations like this: `printf("The difference of %6.2lf and %6.2lf is %6.2lf\n", sub1, sub2, difference);` just seems more natural to me.